# Invoking Scheduler from a Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller, timertask

I have a Spring MVC project and Im currently trying to invoke a scheduler task from my restController.  I have created a StartupBean and which contains a start() that actually invokes the TimerTask. Sample code below

```
public void start() throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("Entering start method {}", System.currentTimeMillis());
    try {
        // running timer task as daemon thread
        TimerTask counterTimerTask = new SessionCountTask();
        Timer counterTimer = new Timer(true);
        counterTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(counterTimerTask, 0, (long) 10 * 1000);//10 sec
        

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error in start method of startup Bean {}", e);
    } finally {
        LOGGER.info("Exiting start method {}", System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

From the Rest controller, Im just invoking the above start() method of the StartupBean. The above method doesnot return anything. The SessionCountTask class  contains a method which returns a JSON object. I wanted to know how I can get the json response to the controller. The scheduler is scheduled to run every 10 secs and I would like to know how to get the response from the task every 10sec and display in the controller.

Any help on this is much appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use [scheduled tasks](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks) in Spring to schedule repeated work, but what does it mean to "display in the controller"? If you want to return something from a method of a controller, it should return when the controller is called, not at some future time. If you want to return some metadata about your running application, adding [custom data to the actuator info endpoint](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-info-actuator-custom) is probably a better choice.

Comment: @DavidConrad,  thanks alot for your response. Basically I wanted to invoke the scheduled tasks by calling the controller.  Also the output of the scheduled task, to be returned as controller output. Would like to know if there is a way to achieve this.